# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

In the next few weeks, the Community Team will be appointing three members of this community to act as provisional Moderators♦ until the community is large enough to hold elections of their own.

We are look for folks who have shown **deep engagement in the community's development** both on in the main Q&A and in the meta community-building activities. Here are some of the traits we look for in an ideal moderator candidate:

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.
>
> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
>   as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
>   after the Beta period.

### Nominating users to serve as moderators for the beta

For each user that you would like to nominate,

- post an answer containing the URLs to both of the user's **main and meta profiles on this site**
- make your answer **community wiki** (there's a checkbox in the answer form) so that candidates without editing privileges can edit in their acceptance
- optionally, link to the user's **Area 51 profile** or a profile from another site, or add a reason why you'd like him/her to moderate during beta
- **self-nominations** (i.e. posting your own profiles) are allowed *and encouraged*
- post each user as a separate answer, and add multiple answers if you wish to nominate multiple users

Additionally, if someone nominates *you*, please **edit the answer** to indicate your approval (or declination). Optionally, add a paragraph or two about yourself.

Commenting is encouraged. If you down-vote a recommendation, you are encouraged to **share why** you did so in the comments, though you are not required to do so. Describing why you up-voted is also encouraged.

For more information about the moderation process, see this blog post:

[**Moderator Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Comment: @Quill Not really. Most of the time, SE goes with the community's picks.

Comment: How many spots are there for early beta? Two? Three?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Well at WB, it was four, correct?

Comment: @fi12 On WB, it was 4 at the time of graduation. But Vincent, the 4th got picked just a few months previously. And I know of at least one beta site that has only two moderators.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Then no idea. But if I were to wager on an estimate, I'd say three.

Comment: @PythonMaster why the edit? Obviously it didn't work as I have four down votes and not a hint of a reason why.

Comment: People are allowed to down-vote, and they are allowed to do it without stating their reasons. This is fundamental to the success of SE. I have therefore rolled back the edit suggesting this ought not be done. (And I say this as the person who has received *the most downvotes*.)

Comment: @Flimzy FYI, I wasn't the one who made that edit. (That was @PythonMaster).

Comment: Agreed @Flimzy... I just have a really bad time with downvoted with no reasons on answers like these...

Comment: Whoever wrote "if someone nominates you, please edit the answer to indicate your approval (or declination)" has forgotten that people can't edit before reaching a certain rep. Thanks @Flimzy for doing "my" editing".

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin [Three is the rule](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), but once in a blue moon just two are chosen.

Comment: @Laure If people make the answers community wiki, that problem ca be solved. fi12, can you add that to the post?

Answer (score 14):

## PythonMaster (Nomination accepted by nominated user)

[PythonMaster LanguageLearning flair http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/flair/64.png](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/pythonmaster)

[image: PythonMaster global flair]

[meta](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/users/64/pythonmaster) • [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/125254/pythonmaster)

Now the fourth user on LanguageLearning.SE (and very active here on meta as well), but also has a reasonable stash of rep on a sampling of other SE sites, not the least of which is [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278543/).

As of this writing, PythonMaster has asked six 10+ voted questions, and has a grand total of 30 posts on the main site. PythonMaster's answers are characterized by in-depth research. As an obviously active participant in this site, I would like to see PythonMaster as a moderator.

---

From [wythagoras](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/who-should-our-moderators-be/209#comment402_209) (slightly edited):

> What is especially important for moderators, in my opinion, is the number of user moderation they did. Some stats: He has done many reviews. To be exact, he has made 157 reviews on the main site so far, out of 972. That is over 16%, which probably means that he is the top reviewer on this site. He is the top voter on this site, with over 200 votes, including 50 downvotes. He is currently the third user by Meta participation, with 10 posts and over 100 votes.

---

Thank for the nomination, in which I accept. Though very young (a teen), this allows me to be able to spend lots of time here doing all sorts of stuff, including moderating and being a normal user at times. I love moderating and moderation is my favorite part of Stack Exchange so expect me to be moderating 24/7!

If I am not, I am happy to contribute on the main and meta site and pour out my inner Language Learner! If I am elected, I hope that our site will be well moderated by me and the other mods and go up and beyond! If I am not... well good luck to all the nominees!

To respond to Flimzy about my lack of experience, though I have quite some rep I have only been a SE member for a year and a half. But I have tried and have caught up to the big lists of rules and procedures and all. Thus I believe I am quite experienced in SE overall and my editing will improve.

Comment: Thnak you Hatchet

Comment: I can't edit this answer, so a comment. What is especially important for moderators, in my opinion, is the number of user moderation they did. Some stats: He has done many reviews. To be exact, he has made 149 reviews on the main site so far, out of 920. That is over 16%, which probably means that he is the top reviewer on this site. He is the top voter on this site, with over 200 votes, including 50 downvotes. He is currently the second user by Meta participation, with 8 posts and over 100 votes. (These stats are form ~2 days ago, so they might be a bit outdated)

Comment: I am excited to see PythonMaster's enthusiastic participation both on the main site and on meta. He does provide a lot of valuable posts, and all indications are that he's operating in good faith. However, I have some serious concerns about his readiness to moderate. As one example, I [rolled back](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/revisions/208/2) one of his edits on this very post, which I believe demonstrates a lack of understanding of the StackExchange model. Now don't get me wrong; I don't think he's acted in "bad faith" or out of malice. I just see a lack of experience.

Comment: @Hatchet I see you just edited my comment in. However, the way you presented it, you say that it is *your* opinion.

Comment: @wythagoras Whoops, sorry! Fixing...

Comment: I no longer have enough rep to check how often PythonMaster actually did this, but based on my memory I'd appreciate greater effort in explaining the reasons for close votes, and perhaps offering suggestions for how to make them on-topic.  That's especially important as a moderator.

Comment: I agree with @Flimzy on this; many of PythonMaster's edits and meta posts demonstrate a lack of familiarity with the SE network. As such, I don't see you being ready to moderate.

Comment: @PythonMaster I have listed out some questions for the candidates to understand your views . I hope you don't mind answering in the meta [discussion](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/254/some-questions-for-moderators).

Comment: Small problem I have: you said [...] so expect me to be moderating 24/7 [...]. However, you haven't visited the main site since May 12.

Comment: Sorry Stack Exchange keeps on crashing for me

Comment: How does a web site "crash" for one user?

Comment: Yes, do tell. How does a website crash? As of now, your unsatisfactory answers to the questions aimed at you represent (to me at least) some unfamiliarity with the SE system.

Comment: I notice that as of right now, you haven't visited the site since May 31. Almost a week...

Comment: Well I am now back... you shouldn't worry about my activity from now on

Comment: @PythonMaster you may be back now, but who knows how long you may be gone in the future. I'm definitely not doubting your capabilities to be a moderator, but if you tend to take long breaks over time, we may want to look into getting a fourth pro tempore moderator appointed later on.

Comment: @PythonMaster so had SE stopped crashing for you yet?

Answer (score 10):

I would like to nominate...

## [Quill](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/8/quill)

Although his main site rep is low, he has been very participatory and thoughtful both on meta and on chat. He's clearly concerned about the long-term health of this site, and has been a driving force behind trying to define our on-topic questions, and narrowing in on what this site thinks is too subjective, etc.

---

From @Quill:

> I accept this nomination. While my reputation is low, I care about the site and I'm trying to do whatever I can to make Language Learning a better place :)

Comment: I accept this nomination. While my reputation is low, I care about the site and I'm trying to do whatever I can to make Language Learning a better place :)

Comment: @Quill I have listed out some questions for the candidates to understand your views . I hope you don't mind answering in the meta [discussion](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/254/some-questions-for-moderators).

Answer (score 9):

### Flimzy

**Global Stats:**

[profile for Flimzy on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/7879.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/7879)

**Main Site:**

[image: profile for Flimzy at Language Learning Stack Exchange]

**Meta:**

[image: profile for Flimzy at Language Learning Meta Stack Exchange]

**Area 51:**

[Area 51 profile for Flimzy http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/39315.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/39315/flimzy)

Should he choose to accept it, I nominate Flimzy.

Flimzy was the user who originally created the Language Learning proposal on Area 51, and he has stuck with it since then. He has been one of the most active users on the site, as well as being active on meta. He is also a pro-tem mod on another site in the SE network, and so is familiar with the tools, privileges, and responsibilities of the position.

---

Thank you for the nomination.  I would be happy to serve in this role, if this is what the community and SE chooses. I do have several years experience on SE, including 5 years experience as pro-tem moderator on [Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/).  I have also been involved, to varying degrees, in a number of sites (both successful and unsuccessful) since private beta, so I do believe I bring a lot of relevant experience to the table, and insight into how to help make a site succeed.

Comment: why this nomination gets heavily downvoted?

Comment: Wow what a debate

Comment: First by Meta participation, first by edits, fourth by votes, 61 reviews.

Comment: @Flimzy I have listed out some questions for the candidates to understand your views . I hope you don't mind answering in the meta [discussion](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/254/some-questions-for-moderators).

Answer (score 9):

<sub>self-nomination</sub>

## Hatchet

[Hatchet LanguageLearning flair http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/flair/85.png](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet)

[Hatchet global flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3296738.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/3296738/hatchet)

[meta](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet) • [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/121679/hatchet)

I currently have two 10+ voted answers and have contributed 19 posts to this site. I've self-taught myself most of what I know of the languages I'm learning (I took some Spanish in high school).

- I have a passion for language learning; it's one of my favorite hobbies.
- I'm in the process of learning two languages: Spanish (~3 years self-taught) and Japanese (<1 year self-taught).
- I'm a huge fan of a self-moderating community.
- I like doing research.

Stats:

- 2nd in reputation
- 99 total reviews (10% of total)
- 2nd editor
- 17th voter
- 13th by meta participation

Comment: Useful stats to maybe add to your answer: 2nd editor on the main site [which is great], 17th voter on the main site [which is reasonable], 9th by Meta participation [which is good], 99 reviews [which is great].

Comment: I can't really see how having no "official language education" beyond high school could be viewed as "unfavorable", it's just not relevant in the choice of a moderator. And as for having never been a moderator on any SE site before, well..  there's got to be a first time for everything in life.

Comment: I have listed out some questions for the candidates to understand your views . I hope you don't mind answering in the meta [discussion](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/254/some-questions-for-moderators).

Answer (score 6):

I would like to stand for selection as Moderator Pro Tempore (through self nomination).

I have been a member of Stack Exchange for five years, with the following profile:
[Tom Au on Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/512193/tom-au),
[Tom Au on Language Learning SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/46/tom-au),
[Tom Au on the meta site](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46/tom-au).

I am featured, with reasonably high reputation scores on several SE language sites including German, Chinese, Spanish, French, and Russian.

I have been active on the site in both private beta and meta, and have a fairly high reputation score. I am not a Moderator on any other site, so there would be no schedule conflict in this regard.

My philosophy toward moderation is a nuanced one; I prefer to correct problems rather than eliminate them, and consider closing/deletion, as something of a last resort, if a post has any redeeming features. On the other hand, I have no problem with "throwing out" content that is clearly bad.

Comment: I have listed out some questions for the candidates to understand your views . I hope you don't mind answering in the meta [discussion](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/254/some-questions-for-moderators).

Answer (score 0):

## fi12

[Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12?tab=profile)

[Language Learning Meta](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12?tab=profile)

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/148313/fi12?tab=stats)

I'm daring to nominate myself. I've been with language learning since its first day on private beta, and as such, I've got the highest reputation on LL, so I'm definitely not lacking in active participation. I'm also the second most active on meta, being the first meta editor and third meta voter.

I'm active on both main and meta. On main, I've made 22 posts with five 10+ questions. On meta, I currently have 14 posts.

If elected, I feel that I could a bring a good amount of both technical expertise as well as strong familiarity with the SE network.

As moderator, I'd like to refine our scope of on-topic questions. Maybe even expand our audience through cross site promotion and advertisement.

I'd have a firm yet guiding hand as a moderator. I would consider closing or deleting questions sparingly (as a single vote from a moderator can close or reopen a question), and as I believe it is something that shouldn't be done if the question can be reformed to be on-topic or answerable. Until the question is edited to be answerable however, I have no problem with closing blatantly off-topic questions.

If I was elected, I would have no other conflicts as I'm not a moderator on any other SE site.

Comment: I don't know why one would downvote your nomination, but almost all of these answers have suffered from multiple downvotes. Some states for you: 3rd by meta participation, 42 reviews, 13th voter, 7th editor.

Comment: Maybe the downvotes come from  your last statement as your main issues are promotion and advertisement rather the site itself

Comment: @fi12 I believe that the power to refine the scope of on-topic questions is unchanged whether one is a moderator or not.

Comment: @PythonMaster I disagree. Someone has to take the lead when it comes to site promotion, and moderators are often some of the best to take the lead, given that they'll often interact with other related sites.

Comment: @PythonMaster exactly, advertisement is an important thing to do for a growing community to expand its audience. None of the other candidates addressed this issue.

Comment: @fi12  I think a site without good quality questions and answers would not survive whatever the advertising, people won't come back after a first visit if they do not like what they see. To build a nice place you need good quality questions & answers, the efforts of the posters as well as those of the appointed moderators who must be patient, open-minded, firm but always nice and polite (knowing that posters aren't always).

Comment: @Laure I totally agree with you there. In early beta, the main focus of all participants on the site should be to build a quality Q+A site, with a fairly well-defined scope as well as providing thoughtful questions and insightful answers. The moderators should be able to regulate the site at its early stages.

Comment: @Laure However, I'm referring to advertising later in the game. It's necessary to promote our site across other related SE sites because yes, we need to build a quality site by asking good questions, but we'll almost never attract new visitors to our site unless somehow we make them realize that this site exists. I don't want this site to stay a niche community of just about 600 to about 1k people.

Comment: I no longer have enough rep to check how often fi12 actually did this, but based on my memory I'd appreciate greater effort in explaining the reasons for close votes, and perhaps offering suggestions for how to make them on-topic.  That's especially important as a moderator.

Comment: @Nathaniel and is this statement from your memory or from a statistic? I assure you, unless there's already a comment explaining why a question is off-topic, I do my best to always leave a comment.

Comment: @fi12 Memory alone.  I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: @fi12 I have listed out some questions for the candidates to understand your views . I hope you don't mind answering in the meta [discussion](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/254/some-questions-for-moderators).