# Feature the nomination of pro-tempore moderators

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation

I think the nomination of pro-tempore mods should have the [featured](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag so that it appears on the sidebar of the main site.

We want the attention, and votes, of users of the main site that are not active in meta.

- [Who should our moderators be?](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/nominate-pro-tempore-moderators)

Comment: It's not in any way an official thing, and it might confuse people into thinking it is if it was featured.

Comment: If you posted that as an answer, @Quill, I could up- or down-vote it. :)

Comment: @Quill That confusion would not happen if the answer was edited to start with `**Not official**: <clarification> \n ---`.

Comment: The surest way to get the attention of our CM is to flag the original question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, but. . .**

On almost every private beta I've participated in, the moderator pro tempore thread, whether posted by a Community Manager (CM) or a regular user, has been marked with the [featured](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag at some point, generally early on. Official or not, it is a very important process, and people who might not always check meta or look at the Hot Meta Posts box need to know.

That said, the way to deal with this is to flag the question, choose the custom flag reason ("in need of moderator attention") and explain why you think the question should be featured. A CM will hopefully see the flag soon and either add the [featured](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag or decline the flag.

Comment: I hadn't [tag:featured] that post yet because the question itself is sort of a mess. With each generation, important context has gone missing, poor advice has been added (some of it is outright incorrect), and the post itself is oddly formatted (like nobody actually read it). I wanted to fix that up a bit before featuring it but got sidetracked. I'll give it a quick once-over, but in future site launches, I am looking to standardize that post and let the system take care of posting/featuring it at the right time.